# How to get exception list from Azure Monitor Common Alert

Tags: azure, webhooks, azure-application-insights

I am getting smart detections alerts:

```
{
   "schemaId":"azureMonitorCommonAlertSchema",
   "data":{
      "essentials":{
         "alertId":"/subscriptions//providers/Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts/",
         "alertRule":"Exception Anomalies - ",
         "severity":"Sev3",
         "signalType":"Log",
         "monitorCondition":"Fired",
         "monitoringService":"SmartDetector",
         "alertTargetIDs":[
            "/subscriptions//resourcegroups//providers/microsoft.insights/components/"
         ],
         "configurationItems":[
            "CHANGEDNAME"
         ],
         "originAlertId":"CHANGEDGUID",
         "firedDateTime":"2022-12-29T04:47:14.5840789Z",
         "description":"Exception Anomalies notifies you of an unusual rise in the rate of exceptions thrown by your app.",
         "essentialsVersion":"1.0",
         "alertContextVersion":"1.0"
      },
      "alertContext":{
         "DetectionSummary":"90 ‘System.Net.Sockets.SocketException’ exceptions (the average volume of the exception in the previous 7 days was 0)",
         "FormattedOccurrenceTime":"2022-12-28T23:59:59Z",
         "DetectedValue":"90",
         "CustomProperty":"0 (over the previous 7 days)",
         "PresentationInsightEventRequest":"/",
         "SmartDetectorId":"ExceptionVolumeChangedDetector",
         "SmartDetectorName":"Exception Volume Changed Detector",
         "AnalysisTimestamp":"2022-12-29T04:47:14.5840789Z"
      },
      "customProperties":null
   }
}
```

In UI of Apllication Insights i can find alerts details and link to

> View detected exceptions

How can i get list of exceptions based only on this notification? What API i need to use?

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to get this work using Application Insights `Events`. Below is the API that worked for me.

**GET**

```
https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/<AppInsights_Application_ID>/events/exceptions?timespan=<timespan>&$filter=<$filter>
```

Below is my complete code in C#

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string URL_requests = "https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/<AppInsights_Application_ID>/events/exceptions?timespan=<timespan>&$filter=<$filter>";

            string apikey = "<Your_API_Key>";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", apikey);
            var req = string.Format(URL_requests);
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(req).Result;
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
    }
}
```